# General way to access method of the enclosing class or parent class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, reflection, methods

How to access method defined in the parent class? Here I have the following inheritance:

```
BaseDTO
|
SortableDTO<T>
|
BaseSearchArticleDTO
|
SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO
```

The method `public void setSortCriteria1(SortDataBean<T> sortCriteria1)` is defined in `SortableDTO<T>`. When I am trying to access this method through the reference of the class `SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO`, as:

```
SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO dto = new SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO();
Method setSortCriteria1 = dto.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setSortCriteria1",SortDataBean.class);
```

I am getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.mhis.posm.web.dto.article.search.SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO.setSortCriteria1(com.mhis.posm.transversal.bean.sort.SortDataBean)
```

But if I do this:

```
Method setSortCriteria1 = dto.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("setSortCriteria1",SortDataBean.class);
```

It is working. Then I found the mistake what I am doing.

[`Class#getDeclaredMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29):

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified declared method of
>   the class or interface represented by this Class object. The name
>   parameter is a String that specifies the simple name of the desired
>   method, and the parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects
>   that identify the method's formal parameter types, in declared order.
>   If more than one method with the same parameter types is declared in a
>   class, and one of these methods has a return type that is more
>   specific than any of the others, that method is returned; otherwise
>   one of the methods is chosen arbitrarily. If the name is "<init>"or
>   "<clinit>" a NoSuchMethodException is raised.

[`Class#getMethod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29)

> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member
>   method of the class or interface represented by this Class object. The
>   name parameter is a String specifying the simple name of the desired
>   method. The parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that
>   identify the method's formal parameter types, in declared order. If
>   parameterTypes is null, it is treated as if it were an empty array.
>
> If the name is "<init>"or "<clinit>" a NoSuchMethodException is raised.
>   Otherwise, the method to be reflected is determined by the algorithm
>   that follows. Let C be the class represented by this object:
>
> - C is searched for any matching methods. If no matching method is found, the algorithm of step 1 is invoked recursively on the superclass of C.
> - If no method was found in step 1 above, the superinterfaces of C are searched for a matching method. If any such
>     method is found, it is reflected.
>
> To find a matching method in a class C:  If C declares exactly one public method with the specified name and exactly the same formal parameter types, that is the method
>   reflected. If more than one such method is found in C, and one of
>   these methods has a return type that is more specific than any of the
>   others, that method is reflected; otherwise one of the methods is
>   chosen arbitrarily.
>
> Note that there may be more than one matching method in a class because while the Java
>   language forbids a class to declare multiple methods with the same signature but
>   different return types, the Java virtual machine does not. This increased flexibility
>   in the virtual machine can be used to implement various language features. For example,
>   covariant returns can be implemented with bridge methods; the bridge method and the
>   method being overridden would have the same signature but different return types.

So I need to call `getMethod` for my case, which solves the issue.

Now I have a utility class:

```
public class ReflectionUtils{

    private ReflectionUtils() {

    }

    public static <T> Method getMethod(Class<T> instanceClass, String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {   
        Method method = null;
        try {
            method = instanceClass.getDeclaredMethod(name,parameterTypes);
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return method;
    }

    public static Object invokeOnMethod(Method method, Object obj, Object... args) {
        try {
            method.setAccessible(true);
            return method.invoke(obj,args);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to change the method `public static <T> Method getMethod(Class<T> instanceClass, String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes)` so that it traps method of any access modifier and belong to anywhere, in the enclosing class, or its superclass or in the interface, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

As per the inheritance principal, the `private` methods are not inherited by the Dervied Classes. So in your example `SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO` instance cannot access the private method declared in `BaseSearchArticleDTO`.

So, with a `Class` object of `SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO`, you can access

- all the methods of `SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO` (`private, protected, public`)
- all the inherited methods of super classes in the hierarchy (`protected, public`)

IMO you can have a fallback mechanism like this

```
try {
        Method m = instanceClass.getMethod(name); // try to get inherited method
        m.setAccessible(true); // if protected setAccessible
        m.invoke(instanceClass.newInstance());
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException ne) {
        try {
            Method m = instanceClass.getDeclaredMethod(name); // try to get declared method in the same class
            m.setAccessible(true); // if private setAccessible
            m.invoke(instanceClass.newInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here is my `ReflectionUtils#getMethod` I came up with:

```
public static Method getMethod(Class<?> instanceClass, String name, Class<?>... parameterTypes) {
    if(ObjectUtils.notEqual(instanceClass,null) && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(name)) {
        Class<?> searchType = instanceClass;

        while (searchType != null) {
            Method[] methods = (searchType.isInterface() ? searchType.getMethods() : searchType.getDeclaredMethods());

            for (Method method : methods) {
                if (name.equals(method.getName()) && (parameterTypes == null || Arrays.equals(parameterTypes, method.getParameterTypes()))) {                           
                    return method;
                }
            }

            searchType = searchType.getSuperclass();
        }
    }       

    return null;
}
```

And it works. Event it returns private method of the super class and after making that method accessible you can invoke that private method with the child object as target instance.

I created a method `test(String message)` in `SortableDTO` which simply prints the message which is passed as argument in the console.

Then I did:

```
SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO dto = new SearchNeedsYearPlus2ArticleDTO();
Method test = ReflectionUtils.getMethod(dto.getClass(),"test",String.class);
System.out.println("Modifier of the method is private? : " + Modifier.isPrivate(test.getModifiers()));
ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(test);
ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(test,dto,"JYM");
```

And voila. It works. Note for the sake of brevity the definition of the method `ReflectionUtils#makeAccessible` and `ReflectionUtils#invokeMethod` has been omitted. :-)

Here is the output:

[image]